# How can I set an alias as Integer in mysql

Tags: mysql, integer, set, alias

Im new at mysql and I havent found anything about it. This is what I want :

```sql
SELECT Uzmanadid, 
       Kurumid, 
       SUM(Bireysel), 
       IF(Kurumid like '%L%', IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 120, 20, 15), 
       IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 90, 20, 15)) AS my_num, 
       (SELECT my_num) * 5 AS another_number 
FROM Tbl_pss2
```

how can I do it?

Comment: see this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Either use subquery/CTE or user-defined variable. PS. Why output fields 3 and 4 have no names/aliases? you do not need them, and use them for only to show expressions which you need for the calculations in the next output fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use alias names in the same select of the same query clause. you need to use subquery or CTE or use the same expression instead of alias name . (but you can use in that alias name in ***having*** clause of the same query to filter some result).

**Using Subquery**

```
SELECT *,t.my_num* 5 AS another_number 
FROM
(SELECT Uzmanadid, 
       Kurumid, 
       SUM(Bireysel), 
       IF(Kurumid like '%L%', IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 120, 20, 15), 
       IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 90, 20, 15)) AS my_num
 FROM Tbl_pss2) as t;
```

**Using CTE**

```
WITH C AS
(SELECT Uzmanadid, 
       Kurumid, 
       SUM(Bireysel), 
       IF(Kurumid like '%L%', IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 120, 20, 15), 
       IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 90, 20, 15)) AS my_num
       FROM Tbl_pss2
)
SELECT *,my_num* 5 AS another_number 
FROM C;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJVpzJE7LpGhfzqedQKh54/0)